# React Native - Passing Strings or Variables via onPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

This probably doesn't just apply to React Native, but I do want to understand what's happening here.

Take the following 5 lines of code. Line 3 will cause the app not to render in Expo.

```
<Button onPress={this.filterOfficeTypePitt} title="Pitt" />
<Button onPress={this.filterOfficeTypeAtl} title="Atl" />
<Button onPress={this.filterOfficeType("pitt")} title="DOES NOT WORK" />
<Button onPress={(e) => this.filterOfficeType("pitt")} title="Pitt" />
<Button onPress={(e) => this.filterOfficeType("atl")} title="Atl" />
```

I somewhat understand what is going on in each line.

Line 1 and 2: Straight forward call to a method within the component.

Line 3: Trying to do the same thing and pass a value. This causes the application to crash. Reason is maximum depth exceeded.

Line 4 and 5: I think this is a function passing an anon function, and suddenly allowing me to add in a string value.

Once I used 4 and 5, I was able to use a single method and have it filter the list. When I was using 1 and 2, I had to have a unique method for each.

I just want to understand what it going on better and why exactly #3 will not work. I'm sure I need at least a better understanding of arrow functions.

Including the code for the helper function. It basically grabs data from an index array and pushes it into a FlatList component.

```
filterOfficeType(officetype){
  let newarray = [];
  this.state.fulldataSource.forEach((element, index) => {
    if(element.office === officetype) {
      newarray.push(element);
    }
  });
  this.setState({
    dataSource:newarray,
    office:officetype
  });
}

filterOfficeTypePitt = () => {
  this.filterOfficeType("pitt");
}
filterOfficeTypeAtl = () => {
  this.filterOfficeType("atl");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Line 3 is executing the function and trying to assign the result of that to `onPress` prop. It never gets there(Why? : explained below)

```
const Button = {
   onPress: this.filterOfficeType("pitt")
}
```

Note: function is being called at the creation of Button object.

whereas the other lines are assigning the function to the onPress prop

```
const Button = {
   onPress: this. filterOfficeTypePitt
}
```

or

```
const Button = {
   onPress: (e) => {
      this.filterOfficeType("pitt")
   }
}
```

Note: the function is not being called a the `Button` object creation rather when something presses that button

And Why Line 3 causes the application to crash is because, it triggers a state change by calling `setState` . When `setState` is called, react will call `render()` again. But this `render()` will execute the function again and this will call `setState` and react will call `render()` again and so the maximum depth exceeded and crash

The main difference between arrow functions and normal functions is the `this` scope. In arrow functions `this` refers to its parent object, where as in normal function `this` refers to itself. You can read more about [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Ah thank you, this helps so much. And I understand the "why" now, which is worth more than any "how to fix" answer.